# Count distinct ID with rowwise altering conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to count with multiple combinations of A, B, C and D.

The following data is given.

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0Vu_J7U)

In this example i like to count the DISTINCT ID if an ID has A = 1, given that B, C and D are 0 over the entire course of data entries per ID.

The problem is that B = 1 in the second data entry of ID 2.

In fact zero entries should be counted.

I tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM (
  SELECT  ID
  FROM tab
  WHERE A = 1 AND B = 0 AND C = 0 AND D = 0
) AS t;
```

The code counts 1 for the first and third data entry for ID 2, but in the second, B = 1.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

PP

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result?

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using?

Comment: The result of `COUNT` should be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that there is no rows with the same id and any of columns not 0, using `EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT T1.ID)
FROM tab T1
WHERE T1.A = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
    FROM tab T2 
    WHERE T2.ID=T1.ID
    AND  (T2.B <> 0 OR T2.C <> 0 OR T2.D <> 0)
)
```